# Same output for same data in GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql

i need two subqueries in one sql query
one of the results maybe is '1,3,2' and the other one is '1,2,3'
how could i judge this two results are equals
i really really need they are equals...

two subqueries are  sql

```
    SELECT t.project_id,GROUP_CONCAT(t.type,',') AS seg_type FROM 
t_project_bid_announce_draft t WHERE t.project_id = '6639124947eb4e0cafc054b9ddcf9f54'
```

and sql

```
    SELECT p.segment_type FROM t_project_segment p  WHERE p.project_id = 
'6639124947eb4e0cafc054b9ddcf9f54'
```

Comment: Sorry but your title is completely unrelated to the question. You compare strings with `=` and take collation into account. That has nothing to do with your actual question, which is about GROUP_CONCAT() and CSV. Feel free to improve it but please don't just revert my edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by`:

```
SELECT t.project_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.type ORDER BY t.type SEPARATOR ',' ) AS seg_type
FROM t_project_bid_announce_draft t
WHERE t.project_id = '6639124947eb4e0cafc054b9ddcf9f54'
```